# How to set fixed bias on transistor 2N2222 for certain specifications?

Tags: transistors, current, resistors, npn, multisim

I'd like to ask how to set fixed bias for this transistor.. It doesn't seem to be working. If anyone know how to calculate it, please tell me.

I wanna adjust two resistor values so that Uce = 5,44V, Ube = 0,655V, Ucc = 12V and Ic (collector current) has to be 2,43 mA.

I tried R2 = (12 - 5,44) / 0,00243 = 2,7kOhm.

But in the second part where I wanna find R1, I don't know Ib (base current). Or can I find it out? I tried looking for BETA, but didn't find anything.

I tried editing Beta in Multisim but I couldn't click Edit Model because it was unclickable.

R1 = (12 - 0,655) / Ib

Any ideas? If yes, please add calculations if you did some and explanation. Thanks forwardly for every sensible comment!

[image]

Comment: I wanna read actual English words. If you don't know beta then you must proceed with trial-and-error, and there is no guarantee that you will be able to get **both** the Vbe and the Ic that you desire.

Comment: I would like to know at least beta.. but i can't find out. I tried Edit Model inside Multisim to see what's inside. But it can't click it, it's not clickable.

Comment: choose R1=2*hFE*Rc but if you want independent of hFE then you use H bias

Comment: Have you read: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/tran_2.html ? There are 2 examples showing the procedure. Another one: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/amplifier/transistor-biasing.html Also plenty of tuturials to be found on Youtube, just search for "bias NPN"  *I tried looking for BETA, but didn't find anything.* Then keep looking, maybe it has a different name, beta (or hfe) is a **crucial** parameter of an NPN transistor so you cannot just ignore it because you couldn't find it.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat, on the other hand, if the transistor doesn't turn on, then voltmeter U2 should read 12 V.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat I think the graphic is misleading. I think that U1 is a voltmeter but for some reason it is not displaying a voltage.

Comment: you must be doing something wrong.. export your model or try again

Comment: Most simulators are going to want to see a ground somewhere.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, man you think I didn't try? I was looking for that Beta in a program, I know it's needed. But I can't even edit it in multisim as  long as it is only a model. And  Alderson, it is showing voltage, but i turned off the simulation where current stays and voltage has been zeroed.

Comment: Add an emitter resistor.   Beta (and to a lesser extent, Vbe) are not constant, you MUST swamp their influence.   A constant voltage applied to the base will bias the transistor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem has been solved, I found Beta(min) and Beta(max) and somehow tried to find the Beta so the values could match with all the pre-defined values. I was experimenting a bit but it took a time.